# Problems in using pip to install tensorflow on iMac El Capitan?

Tags: macos, python-2.7, installation, tensorflow, osx-elcapitan

I've followed [the installation guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/get_started/os_setup.html#pip-installation) but the final install step failed.
My installed python version: 
 `python 2.7.10 (default, Oct 23 2015, 19:19:21) 
 [GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.0.0 (clang-700.0.59.5)] on darwin`

I have used the following two commands to install tensorflow

1. `sudo pip install --upgrade $TF_BINARY_URL`
2. `sudo  -H pip install --upgrade $TF_BINARY_UR`

Somehow I found Protobuf was not installed  under my Python 2.7,
so I followed the suggestion from the installation site,

3. `pip install protobuf`

It failed to install protobuf, see the error message below.

Please help

## Thanks in advance

**When using the first command, got the following messages:**

```
The directory '/Users/David/Library/Caches/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
The directory '/Users/David/Library/Caches/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
```

**Then as suggested, I used the second command, then error messages were:**

```
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-8.1.2-py2.7.egg/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-8.1.2-py2.7.egg/pip/commands/install.py", line 317, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-8.1.2-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_set.py", line 736, in install
    requirement.uninstall(auto_confirm=True)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-8.1.2-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_install.py", line 742, in uninstall
    paths_to_remove.remove(auto_confirm)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-8.1.2-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_uninstall.py", line 115, in remove
    renames(path, new_path)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-8.1.2-py2.7.egg/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 267, in renames
    shutil.move(old, new)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 299, in move
    copytree(src, real_dst, symlinks=True)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 208, in copytree
    raise Error, errors
Error: [('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/__init__.py', '/tmp/pip-9CKE1y-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/__init__.py', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/tmp/pip-9CKE1y-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/__init__.py'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/__init__.pyc', '/tmp/pip-9CKE1y-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/__init__.pyc', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/tmp/pip-9CKE1y-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/__init__.pyc'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/markers.py', '/tmp/pip-9CKE1y-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/markers.py', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/tmp/pip-9CKE1y-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/markers.py'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/markers.pyc', '/tmp/pip-9CKE1y-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/markers.pyc', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/tmp/pip-9CKE1y-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/markers.pyc'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib', '/tmp/pip-9CKE1y-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/tmp/pip-9CKE1y-uninstall/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib'")]
```

**For the command 3, the error message:**

```
Command "/usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/h5/vh7y894j0js3vqkv_hz4qk6w0000gn/T/pip-build-KWqDAq/protobuf/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/h5/vh7y894j0js3vqkv_hz4qk6w0000gn/T/pip-5RoEnu-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/h5/vh7y894j0js3vqkv_hz4qk6w0000gn/T/pip-build-KWqDAq/protobuf/
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a result of [System Integrity Protection](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204899) in El Capitan. I was able to install using the following:

```
# Note the lack of "sudo" and the addition of "--user"
pip install --user --upgrade $TF_BINARY_URL
# And then to ensure that the user-specific packages are used,
# I had to start python from the user-site packages directory
cd $(python -m site --user-site)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem when installing awsebcli,

try:

```
sudo pip install protobuf --ignore-installed six
```